# Getting error trying to use TinyMCE cloud in my Angular 13 app - Module 'tinymce' has no exported member 'RawEditorSettings'

Tags: angular, tinymce

I have created a new angular app and have installed these:

npm install --save @tinymce/tinymce-angular
npm install --save @types/tinymce

I've included the EditorModule in app.module.ts

I have correctly included my apiKey in the  element

When I try to run (with npm start), I get this error:

Error: node_modules/@tinymce/tinymce-angular/editor/editor.component.d.ts:4:35 - error TS2305: Module '"tinymce"' has no exported member 'RawEditorSettings'.

4 import { Editor as TinyMCEEditor, RawEditorSettings } from 'tinymce';

Any help I get will be much appreciated

Comment: Basically I've done everything (for the tiny cloud instructions) in this tinymce document (https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/angular/#tinymceangularintegrationquickstartguide) and am still getting this error.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to use RawEditorOptions in place of the older RawEditorSettings, and my code works with the newer version of tinymce.

Answer (score 1):

v5 of tinymce was the trick for me. Seems `RawEditorSettings` has been removed from v6

```
 npm i tinymce@5.10.3
```

Answer (score 1):

Must be using an old version. If you are using version 5 of the wrapper, having tinymce v5 as a dependency should do the trick in case types are not right. Version 6 of the wrapper should work regardless of the tinymce version running.